# find count inside include for sequelizejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Dears

Am trying to select count inside include for sequelizejs, but am getting error like below

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeBaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'User.Orders.id' in 'field list'
    at Query.formatError (/Users/abdulazizaltaleb/Desktop/Ajeer-Dashboard_clone/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:175:14)
    at Query._callback (/Users/abdulazizaltaleb/Desktop/Ajeer-Dashboard_clone/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:49:21)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/abdulazizaltaleb/Desktop/Ajeer-Dashboard_clone/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:86:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/Users/abdulazizaltaleb/Desktop/Ajeer-Dashboard_clone/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:88:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/abdulazizaltaleb/Desktop/Ajeer-Dashboard_clone/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/Users/abdulazizaltaleb/Desktop/Ajeer-Dashboard_clone/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:75:12)
    at Protocol.write (/Users/abdulazizaltaleb/Desktop/Ajeer-Dashboard_clone/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/abdulazizaltaleb/Desktop/Ajeer-Dashboard_clone/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:252:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:239:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:197:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:589:20)
```

All what i need is to return data from Model and include this data with others to get the count only

below my code and i used i some explanation in the code

```
models.Order.findAll({
    where : {
        userId : {
            $and : {
                $notIn: ['null']
            }
        },
        serviceId : {
            $and : {
                $notIn: ['null']
            }
        }
    },
    limit : 10,
    pageLength : 500,
    order: '`id` DESC',
    include: [
        {
            model : models.User,attributes : ['firstName','lastName','phoneNumber','rankId'],
            include: [
                {
                    model : models.Order
                    // return the count for orders
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    attributes: ['id','serviceId','orderStatus',
        [sequelize.Sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.Sequelize.col('User.Orders.id')), 'count']
    ],
    group: ['`User.Orders`.`userId`']
```

so in the line

```
// return the count for orders
```

am trying to get the count for model

```
model : models.Order
```

thank you